# Do I require transit visa to stay at Narita International Airport?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, japan, airport-transfer

I am an Indian citizen and traveling to Seattle (on Business visa) through Tokyo (Layover for 9 hours). I don't have any such plans to go outside from the airport in Tokyo. Do I still need a Transit visa for staying in Airport transit zone in Tokyo?

Do I need to cross the Immigration boxes while transferring the flights?

Comment: @SheikPaul Please check out the comments on accepted answer and other answers as well. It's very confusing but everyone is saying that If you have an overnight layover then You need a transit visa.

Comment: I did. It says if you have an overnight (where of course you would want to go sleep in a hotel) you need a visa. You stated specifically you don't have plans to exit. Thus no transit visa required. Simple.

Comment: That means the airport is not functional for 24 hours? Can't I stay in the airport for the whole night?

Comment: Amit, it says the Airport is closed to flights overnight, and **people are allowed to stay**. Read all the comments. Don't worry Narita airport folks won't throw you out at night when you don't have a  visa to legally exit the airport :)

Comment: @SheikPaul I agree with what you said. This isn't just for Tokyo either. Most. if not all. International Airports that open 24 hrs will not require a visa if you never leave the security area. Also of note is that Narita did actually used to shut (it has since changed to be 24 hrs a day) and there have been cases of people being moved on depending where in the airport your decide to park yourself for 9 hours (so choose a place that is not likely to get security attention / be in the way / make you miss your flight).